# Performance issues with lookup

Tags: ssis, lookup

i am facing a terrible issue with the SSIS packages. In my packages I have one lookup and i have a condition like this

OLEDB Source has around 400,000 records and lookup table has around 1,200,000 records. Both the tables can grow but the one which is coming from the OLEDB source will have max around 900,000. Both table has around 40-50 columns to lookup.

```
There are 51528912896 bytes of physical memory with 32689860608 bytes free. There are 4294836224 bytes of virtual memory with 249348096 bytes free. The paging file has 120246493184 bytes with 109932904448 bytes free.
```

is there is any effective solution to this?

Comment: What caching mode are you using?

Comment: Full cache.. I tried with partial cache too but that has stopped responding after 12,456 records.

Comment: Partial cache wont do any good if it does not work with Full Cache. Sadly, there are no work arounds for lookups. You either get the performance or you dont. The value (destination) that you are looking up, is it an index or something else?

Comment: Do you really need 40-50 columns in that lookup? In Partial Cache mode, how much memory have you allocated to it.

Comment: Yes, that's the business requirement. I don't know how to allocate any memory to ssis or SQL.. but i know that it is 48GB server with 8 GB ram

Comment: Check this article which might help u  http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2010/03/18/ssis-lookup-component-tuning-tips.aspx

Comment: If both Source and lookup table in the same database. We can use the joins so that all lookup operations will be done server end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At that scale I would be considering using a Merge Join transformation instead of a Lookup. Order by your keys in your OLE DB Source SQL code and define the sort manually (ref http://www.ssistalk.com/2009/09/17/ssis-avoiding-the-sort-components/ ).  While slower than a cached lookup, this design tends to scale better in terms of memory use.